# Rails - Has and belongs to many ... condition with multiple joins of the same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a model conversation with a has_and_belongs_to_many-association of users

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I want to search conversations that two users are associated to.

I'm thinking about to join the users-table twice and use and AND-condition. I have tried to use AREL but i haven't got it to work correctly.

A workaround is to use the & operator on the users conversations like:

```
@first_user.conversations & @second_user.conversations
=> Returns conversations that both users are subscribed to.
```

But that leads to multiple sql-queries which i think can't be the best option.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Something like this `Coversation.includes(:users).where(["user_id IN (?)", [1,2]])`

Comment: That was my initial try. But like this you will also get conversations that only one user is assigned to. But i want the conversations that both users are assigned to.

Comment: It will give both i guess.

Comment: Yes but i need exactly the conversations that both users are assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Conversation.joins(:users).where('user_id in (?)',[1,2]).group(:id).having('count(user_id) > 1')
```